# Jquery close popup on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this jquery to show my popup,

```
//ResetPassword Popup display
$(document).ready(function () {
var passwordExpiredVal = $("#isPasswordExpired").html();
if (passwordExpiredVal == "True") {
    $("#ResetPasswordModal").modal({
        show: 'true'
        });
    };
});
```

I use this jquery to pass the new typed password to controller action ON CLICK, once the save button is clicked I want the popup to close

```
//Reset Password submit
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitSave").on("click", function () {
        var confirmPassword = $("#txtLgnPasswordConfirmReset").val();
        var passwordReset = {
            UserName: $("#txtLgnUsername").val(),
            Password: $("#hdnOldPassword").val(),
            NewPassword: $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val()
        }
        if (passwordReset.NewPassword != confirmPassword) {
        notifyMessage.showNotifyMessage('error', 'The passwords entered should match', false);
            $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val("");
            $("#txtLgnPasswordConfirmReset").val("");
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/PasswordReset",
                data: passwordReset,
                success: function () {
                    $("#ResetPasswordModal").modal({
                    show: 'false'
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My jquery function is not helping...

```
success: function () {
                    $("#ResetPasswordModal").modal({
                    show: 'false'
                    });
                },
```

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please check the answer below as I removed my comment. and mark it if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is unnecessarily initializing the modal again on that element.

Use `modal('hide')` : **[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#.modal('hide'))**,

```
success: function () {
    $('#ResetPasswordModal').modal('hide');
},
```

If you further wish to use this again, `'toggle'` would be a better option.

```
$('#ResetPasswordModal').modal('toggle')
```